# How to rename multiple sheets that are copied from a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy all the sheets from a spreadsheet to a new spreadsheet and then rename the sheets in the new spreadsheet with the same name as the original sheet and then replace the sheet in the new spreadsheet if the sheet already exists.
So, I was able to copy the multiple tabs in the new spreadsheet, I am new to app script so need some help with renaming and replacing the existing sheets.

```
function copySheetsToNewSS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  for(var n in ss.getSheets()){
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[n];// look at every sheet in spreadsheet
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1goBAwtP1clFCt_UQEn2DEPgGQzgSJ5vppG52ouYRGI");
    var name = sheet.getName();//get name
    sheet.copyTo(destination);// copy content
    }
    destination.deleteSheet(destination.getSheets()[0]);// remove original "Sheet1"
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function copySheetsToNewSS() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1goBAwtP1clFCt_UQEn2DEPgGQzgSJ5vppG52ouYRGI");
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(sh => sh.copyTo(dss).setName(sh.getName()));
  dss.deleteSheet(dss.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

[copyTo(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

This should replace all of the sheets by deleting all of the sheets except the first one before copying and then deleting the zeroth one after.

```
function copySheetsToNewSS() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1goBAwtP1clFCt_UQEn2DEPgGQzgSJ5vppG52ouYRGI");
  dss.getSheet().forEach((s,i) => {if(i>0)dss.deleteSheet(s)});
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(sh => sh.copyTo(dss).setName(sh.getName()));
  dss.deleteSheet(dss.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Cooper! This was really helpful. Can you also please tell how can I replace a sheet if it already exists, with the new sheet copied so that it has the updated data.